# How to select records in a track with gaps not greater than 5 minutes between each record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having a lot of records from a GPS device, which I need to show as an route on a map. Records combine a route when the time between them records is not greater than 5 minutes.

Lets say my database looks like:

```
id       date
-------  ---------------------
1        2013-01-10 11:00:00.0
2        2013-01-10 11:01:15.0
3        2013-01-10 11:02:15.0
4        2013-01-10 11:03:15.0
5        2013-01-10 11:04:45.0
6        2013-01-10 11:15:00.0
7        2013-01-10 12:00:00.0
8        2013-01-10 12:00:50.0
```

In this case records 1-5 and 7-8 need to form a route.

I'm trying to write a query for this, but I'm stuck. I managed to perform the operation after the database, but that is something you should not want (you have to retrieve ALL the records etc.)

Has someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get individual segements by simply comparing each entry with its successor

```
SELECT 
    f.ID AS from_ID,
    t.ID AS to_ID
FROM
    GPSTable AS f 
JOIN GPSTable AS t
    ON f.ID = t.ID-1 
WHERE
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, f.Date, t.Date) < 300
;
```

If there exists an entry (A,B) and another entry (B,C), you know that you have a path from (A->B->C).

The next step would then be to collect all those path segments. This could be done by a recursive query, but I am not familiar with mySQL.

Comment: @GeorgeBoot: Thanks for the correction in how to calculate the difference between two datetime values in mySQL.